# is it possible to run some php code within a wordpress page?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to access a DB table and render it in some data grid format using php on a dedicated wordpress page, accessible to members of a certain group. Is this at all possible with wordpress or is there another way to do so?

using wp 3.5 on linux system + mysql
thanks

Comment: This has already been answer on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress

Answer (score 6):

You can [create a simple plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and either [add a shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to run your php, or [filter `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) and add a [conditional check](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for your specific page and inject your DB output. This way your code will be independent of the theme and more portable. Use the [`wpdb` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to query any database /table.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "page" here?
You can throw whatever PHP you want into a page *template*. If this is a more or less one-off thing, what you should probably do is use the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to just embed it.

If you mean you want to do this within *content* arbitrarily ie. through the post editor, that's disallowed by core, but there are plugins that add the capability. The most recent one I'm aware of is [Allow PHP in Posts and Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/), (there are others and you might want to look around) but this is something that's generally advised against unless you absolutely trust every single person that might have access.

Comment: Custom page templates are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that allow you to run php code in the post content. Here are a couple:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-for-posts/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/